# Getting element height

Tags: properties, typescript, angular

I was curious if I can get element properties form component template.
So I have made simple div with class and I've made this class:

```ts
export class viewApp{

  elementView: any;
  viewHeight: number;
  myDOM: Object;

  constructor() {
    this.myDOM = new BrowserDomAdapter();
  }

  clickMe(){
    this.elementView = this.myDOM.query('div.view-main-screen');
    this.viewHeight = this.myDOM.getStyle(this.elementView, 'height');
  }
}
```

`getStyle()`, `query()` are from [BrowserDomAdapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html).
My problem is when I try to get height it is `null`, but when I set some height by `setStyle()` and then I get it by `getStyle()` it returns proper value.
After checking DOM and styles in browser I discovered that is because of two CSS elements. One is: `.view-main-screen[_ngcontent-aer-1]{}` and second one is `element{}`.
`.view-main-screen` has some stylings, but element is empty. When I add styles by `setStyle()` it appears in `element{}`. Why is that? How can I get element properties by using Angular2?

Answer (score 77):

The correct way is to use `@ViewChild()` decorator:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html

**Template:**

```
<div class="view-main-screen" #mainScreen></div>
```

**Component:**

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class viewApp{

      @ViewChild('mainScreen') elementView: ElementRef;
      viewHeight: number;

      constructor() {
      }

      clickMe(){
        this.viewHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
      }
}
```

That should do it but obviously you need to add your Component decorator.

**Edit:**

For Angular 8 or later you need to provide the 2nd parameter in ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('mainScreen', {read: ElementRef, static:false}) elementView: ElementRef;
```

Comment: if that does not work, we may have to use ` @ViewChild('mainScreen', {read: ElementRef}) elementView: ElementRef;`

Answer (score 18):

**update2**

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

someMethod() {
   console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
}
```

Accessing `nativeElement` directly is discouraged but current Angular doesn't provide other ways as far as I know.

**update**

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452#issuecomment-220460761

> mhevery commented 12 days ago
>   We have decided to remove Ruler service, and so it is not part of the public API.

**original**

As far as I know the `Ruler` class should provide that functionality
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler.ts if this isn't enought you probably need to access `elementRef.nativeElement` and use direct DOM access and functions provided by the elements.

```ts
new Ruler(DOM).measure(this.elRef).then((rect: any) => {
});
```

Rules service is safe in WebWorker. 
See also the comments on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6515#issuecomment-173353649

Comment: Okey, but how can I use it? I try to import Ruler or Rectangle but compiler throws error. Anyway, thanks for reply!

Comment: I don't know about TS imports, I use only Dart. The only place I found it in use is https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3c8fa8c50d820e3317bc40292c73df03c8b23e86/modules/angular2/test/platform/browser/ruler_spec.ts

Comment: Good find, @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Why is accessing the native element discouraged?

Comment: It's an old answer, the Angular team had a strong opinion about that back then. Their stance weakened. Accessing it prevents you from usung server-side-rendering and web worker, but not everyone wants to anyway, therefore it's your call what's more important to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <div #getElementHeight>
      Height
  </div>
```

Height of element is {{ getElementHeight.offsetHeight }}

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClick($event.currentTarget)"></div>

itemClick(dom){
  var height=dom.clientHeight;
  // ...
}
```