# How to find children and parents of a DOM element in Angular2

Tags: angular

I know I can obtain the DOM element of a component with

```
constructor(el: ElementRef){}
```

But how do I access its children (e.g. by searching by class or id) and host?

```
el.nativeElement.children
el.nativeElement.parent
el.nativeElement.host
```

all don't work.

I've searched all over for an answer, with no luck. Thank you very much for any help.

**EDIT** Thanks to yurzui's comment I realised `el.nativeElement.children` works after the component's view is initialised. However I still can't access the host element.

Also, as JB Nizet pointed out, it is inelegant do manipulate DOM elements in Angular2. The only thing about my DOM element I need in the component's class, though, is the element's width. If I knew how to bind this value to a class attribute, I would have solved the issue without accessing the DOM. I had previously tried something like

```
<div [width] = "style.width"></div>
```

(`width` an attribute of the class of my component, whose view containse the above div) but I can't get it to work.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. Doing DOM manipulation in Angular is a design smell. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: @JBNizet Point taken, I don't like it either.. but I need the width of the container of a component in order to perform some calculations. If the host HTML element is inaccessible I can trick it by putting `<div class = "width-catcher" style= "width: 100%"></div>` in my view, but I still need the width of the `.width-catcher` child. My component view's width isn't 100%, so standard approaches fail.

Comment: try to use your code in ngAfterViewInit event. https://plnkr.co/edit/iTmsNaIoU9NNUEFRe4kG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, `el.nativeElement.children` works after the view is initialised. I still can't access the host though.

Comment: Why would you want to access the `.host` property of the element? `el.nativeElement` is the host element. Using `@ViewChildren()` would be a better approach if possible.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry for the confusion, I mean the host of the host element.

Comment: That's `.parent` except when you use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`

Comment: Angular provides rudimentary support for this using the `Ruler` service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919738/getting-element-height-angular-2/34919830#34919830

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `console.log(el.nativeElement.parent)` in the constructor, after the view is init, yields `undefined` and I'm not using `encapsulation`.

Comment: Can you build a Plunker that allows to reproduce? (template https://plnkr.co/edit/wnLWAW?p)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you - I might do that tomorrow when I have more time, I've imported external libraries and it's a little complicated. I'll have a look at `Ruler`.

Comment: Maybe you need to use parentNode property instead parent?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

Comment: @yurzui Yes that's it! Thanks a lot (if you answer I'll accept). Thanks to everyone else who commented as well.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try to use your code in **ngAfterViewInit** event.

And you need to use **parentNode** property instead parent

```
export class App {
  el: ElementRef;
  constructor(el: ElementRef){
    this.el = el; 
  },
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const hostElem = this.el.nativeElement;
    console.log(hostElem.children);
    console.log(hostElem.parentNode);
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/iTmsNaIoU9NNUEFRe4kG?p=preview

Answer (score 14):

Since this.el.nativeElement.children returns Array of child nodes, you can simply do this.el.nativeElement.children[0].

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit,  ElementRef } from '@angular/core'; 

export class MyComponent implements ngAfterViewInit {
  el: ElementRef;

  constructor(el: ElementRef){
    this.el = el; 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]);
     console.log(this.el.nativeElement.children[0].offsetHeight);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Children:**

```
el.nativeElement.querySelector('.some-child-class-name');
```

**Parents:**

```
el.nativeElement.closest('.some-parent-class-name')
```