# Access the offsetHeight of an element in angular2 component

Tags: angular, dom, typescript

I am wondering if there is anyway to access the attributes of a DOM element in an Angular2 component, **without** using nativeElement to maintain DOM independence.

I currently use renderer to **set** DOM attributes. However, I'm unsure of the correct solution to **retrieve** the values of DOM element attributes without using accessing the DOM directly with nativeElement. [This link advises to do this, however was posted in June](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452#issuecomment-220460761) Have we come up with something better since then?

My current implementation is as follows:

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'div',
  templateUrl: './div.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./div.component.css']
})

export class DivComponent{ 

    @ViewChild('element') ele: ElementRef;

        overlayMargin: string;

    constructor(private el:ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        this.overlayMargin = this.ele.nativeElement.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }

}
```

I set the margin whenever the window gets resized. **The main portion of code to focus on is** `this.ele.nativeElement.offsetHeight`

To my understanding grabbing the attribute value in this manner makes my component DOM dependent, and the negative implication is not being able to use web workers in the future.

I noticed solutions using things like [Ruler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919738/getting-element-height-angular-2) however it was [removed](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452#issuecomment-220460761) and in that last link, they advise to "just access the DOM directly for now" However, that was in June 2016, it's now 2017, I've looked around, and have not found any apparent solutions. Has a new API been made to address this? I would like to avoid accessing the DOM directly if at all possible to maintain component independence.

### So my question is: Is there a better way of doing this? Or is `.nativeElement` and `ViewChild` the best method for now? (As of 1/18/2017)

Comment: There is no way without direct DOM access to read from the DOM. It seems direct DOM access is fine nowadays as long as you're not using server side rendering or webworkers.

Comment: That's what I feared. I realize that server side rendering isn't possible because there is no DOM yet, so those .nativeElements will be undefined. What if for server side rendering we spin up another server in parallel which runs a Selenium like browser like the ones used for E2E testing. Then we could tell angular to use that server side DOM to obtain the initial values, maybe even try to get the devices width and height from their initial request to make the Selenium browser similar to the clients. 

This might be a good feature request as long as the resource consumption isn't crippling.

Comment: I haven't used SSR but I assume there is a way to figure out if the code is runnimg on client or server and them just skip the call to DOM and retuen some default value

Comment: The feature request could be a new option when server side rendering is enabled. If the environment also has a server which hosts a browser, when server side rendering is enabled we would have a DOm on the server which mirrored closely what the client has, we could add a few more arguments to redirect the app to use that server side DOM for all instances where the DOM is directly accessed for the initial render. Once the app is rendered then we switch back to the users location and serve them the application.

Comment: Hmm, that could work as well :) and the default value way would probably be a lot more performant I'll give it some thought.

Comment: I don't see the benefit. Why not just use a default value? Selenium is quite slow add makes setup more complicated.

Comment: I'll try it out, if it works I'll share my implementation :) Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the nativeElement directly is indeed discouraged but this is the only way to do it because angular doesn't provide an other way for this.

I currently use this in my application to avoid using the native element in my TypeScript code

```
(window:resize)="onNavResize(navbar.getBoundingClientRect())"
```