# Is there a way to generate child components dynamically according to the height in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am working on a requirement that put some data into some tables, and each table's height must be less than some given value. For example, there are 10 data, and the max of height per table is '100px', if all of them put into one table, and then the table's height is '150px', so the code must detect that and change to put them into two or three table. How can I do this?

Comment: why not fixed the height of the rows? it's easer count rows that count pixels

Comment: because some fields are rich text, so I can't set fixed height for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Till I understand your need, you have to get the table's height data in `ngFor` loop.

You can get the height of the div by this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40785981/8612835).

Based on that you need to set logic with simple `if - else` condition. If the size of the `div` is <= `{{this.yourSize}}` then allow to add data in table else design new table.

Comment: Thank you, I do like this and got the height of the table, but I can't refresh the component at that time. What really trouble me is that, I think there should be a loop for get each table's height and then adjust the table's count, re-paint the component and do the loop again.

Comment: You may use the host listener of window change and when you get event at that time you may call some function to re-paint the data. And make sure you used the reusability of code.

Comment: I'm sorry for reply so late, I finished the question in other way but I don't think it's good enough. Would you please give me a little introduction about host listener? I've never heard that.

Comment: Please do little search on that, You will get more information from google. :) Let me know if you need any other help. :)